# MaterialAutoCompleteTextView dropdown selected item background color

Tags: android, material-components-android, materialautocompletetextview

I am using the MaterialAutoCompleteTextView component. I would like if possible to set a different background color for selected item.

This is the current UI:

[image]

I would like to achieve this:

[image]

Any idea how to solve it?

Answer (score 1):

I asked in the github and the solution is update the material library and use the property MaterialAutoCompleteTextView.setSimpleItemSelectedColor() to achieve that.

(only available since 1.7.0-alpha02.)

https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/issues/2754

Comment: i am trying this but it didn't work. My dropdown is inside a bottom sheet view. is that make any difference?